# Optimize CPU Usage in Nginx and PHP5-FPM

Tags: wordpress, nginx, cpu-usage, php

I have a site serving **Wordpress** + **Nginx** + **PHP5-FPM + **WP Super Cache**. The server is a Digital Ocean droplet, with 4gb of memory and 2 cores. At times (like yesterday), CPU usage is around 90% and the site will become very slow. Most of the time it is between 30-50%.

Other articles I've read about "high" Nginx and PHP5-FPM usage mention rates of 40%+ for a single process. I'm not experiencing anything that unusual, but I wonder if my statistics are reasonable, given the machine and my Nginx configuration.

I've pasted nginx.conf here: http://pastebin.com/fD9HjqpB
General wordpress configuration file (for Nginx): http://pastebin.com/CVkHZtvU
And the site-specific config here: http://pastebin.com/KsVECwEa

---

```
Cpu(s): 47.8%us, 37.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 14.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4049968k total,  1363176k used,  2686792k free,    35376k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   549984k cached
```

---

```
PID  USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR  S   %CPU  %MEM  TIME+     COMMAND
667  mysql     20  0  1314m  85m  7908 S   89    2.2   17:10.21  mysqld
1679 www-data  20  0  229m   54m  3836 S   15    1.4   0:04.23   php5-fpm
1688 www-data  20  0  234m   59m  3696 R   12    1.5   0:01.21   php5-fpm
1682 www-data  20  0  237m   61m  3780 S   10    1.6   0:02.93   php5-fpm
1681 www-data  20  0  231m   56m  3848 S    9    1.4   0:03.26   php5-fpm
1684 www-data  20  0  237m   62m  3816 S    9    1.6   0:02.15   php5-fpm
1680 www-data  20  0  240m   65m  5204 S    7    1.7   0:03.47   php5-fpm
1686 www-data  20  0  237m   62m  3836 S    6    1.6   0:01.33   php5-fpm
1687 www-data  20  0  237m   62m  3820 S    6    1.6   0:00.97   php5-fpm
1691 www-data  20  0  229m   54m  3828 S    6    1.4   0:00.52   php5-fpm
721  www-data  20  0  130m   57m  1104 S    0    1.5   0:00.48   nginx
```

---

Is there anything I could be optimizing further to lower CPU usage and avoid the 90%+ usage periods? Obviously we could increase the size of the droplet, but I'm hoping to avoid scaling with hardware vs. just optimizing if there is opportunity.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: with the limited data you have provided, I would say the first thing to do is check the bot activity on your WP installation. Bad bots make up some 30-50% of traffic that you receive, so put forth some effort there to block them. After that, you could always look into using some of your RAM for caching static pages, using either memcache, or the ramdisk its self. also, using fast cgi with wp total cache would be better in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the info, will dig in to each of those. What other details would be helpful to include in my question?